# NodeJS passe 2 querys to html

Tags: node.js

I have a small App created by NodeJS. 
Before i render a HTML depending on URL, i need informations from my database.
But on my current way i can execute only on query.

```
app.get('/technology/:technology',function(req,res){    
    var res1,res2;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://xx.xxx', function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;     
        var db = client.db('test');      
        res1=db.collection('col1').find().toArray( function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            client.close();
        });
        res2=db.collection('col2').find().toArray( function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            client.close();
        });
    }); 
    res.render('technology',{tech1:res1,tech2:res2});
});
```

I tried to save the result on variable but it doesn´t worked. The Result keeps the correctly data. I veryfied that by writing the result to console.

Answer (score 0):

Queries are asynchronous functions. You either execute queries with nested callback functions or use async/await keywords.

Answer (score 0):

all NodeJs io functions are async thats why you dont see the render as it happens a lot earlier then you mongo queries. try working with Promises

```js
app.get('/technology/:technology',function(req,res){    

     MongoClient.connect('mongodb://xx.xxx')
    .then(client => {
        const db = client.db('test');      
        return Promise.all([
            db.collection('col1').find().toArray(),
            db.collection('col2').find().toArray()
          ])
     })
     .then([res1,res2] =>{
        res.render('technology',{tech1:res1,tech2:res2});
     })
     .catch(err => console.log(err))
   
});
```

Comment: ok i understand. In your example i can´t see which db you choose. You easylie use db. Do i have to use it like i did or i should declare the database in url by following prefix ":test"?

Comment: fixed it. by the way it is best to connect once on the app start up and not create a new connection every route

Comment: ok now i understood. btw you missed something when you pass res1 and res2: .then(([res1,res2]) =>... Is it a diffrent to connect on every route? because if the route don´t match with url it will not executed. In the end on both ways we have only one connection? Am i wrong?